# Thread safe class consuming several resources

Tags: c++, multithreading

In a C++11 code (and probably using OpenMP), I want to process several resources while exploiting the parallelism offered by cores of my CPU (therefore using threads). My problem is to protect the "context" of a class from concurrency but I'm not sure how to reach this goal ! It's more a design problem than a pure C++ code problem because, currently, on a single thread, my code works perfectly. Now I want to adapt it to multi-threads.

Let's suppose my CPU has 4 cores and 4*N resources to process. What I would like to obtain is: launch 4 threads and each thread process N resources. Say like this, it seems to be concurrency-free, but unfortunately it's not !

My current concrete case is to load resources from files into c++ class but you have to see my issue as a more general case.

By context, I mean: the current state of a c++ class stored in variable members. By resource, I mean (in my concrete case): a file (ascii or binary not important) to read and store data into a C++ class. Resources are heterogeneous (by example sounds, textures but what exactly they are is not very important). The order of resources loading is not important to me (as well to have balanced CPU charges).

My current code, on a single thread and for a single kind of resource, looks like the following pseudo code:

```
class Loader { ... };
class Resource { ... };
string filenames[N] = { "file1.txt", "file2.txt", ... "fileN.txt" };
Resource resources[N];

for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    Loader.loadFromFile(filename[i], &resources[i]);
}
```

For multi-thread, using the OpenMP formalism, I thought about to write something like :

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    Loader.loadFromFile(filename[i], &resources[i]);
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm scared it will be not as easy as written in the pseudo-code, because of the "context" stored inside the class Loader which get it not thread safe. Here my current implementation (simplified):

```
template <class T>
class ILoader
{
public:
    ...
    virtual void loadFromFile(std::string const& filename, T &resource) = 0;
};

class Resource1Loader : public ILoader<Resource1>
{
public:
    virtual void loadFromFile(std::string const& filename, Resource1 &resource) override
    {
        m_infile.open(filename, ...);
        ...
        resource.xxx = m_infile.read(...);
    }

private:
    std::ifstream m_infile; // The context
};
```

And so long for all kind of resources (Resource1, Resource2 ... ResourceN).

*Note: why I implemented classes like this ? To have a LoaderManager containing a list of loaders (== a hash table where key is the file extension and where the value is a loader) and a ResourceManager containing a list of resources that Loaders returned.*

m_infile is my "not-thread safe context". It's my file descriptor for reading the file. I'm blocked on how to protect it.

Here my solutions but I do not like them:

1. Use a mutex to protect the whole code of loadFromFile(), I will lose all my parallelism.
2. I think it's overkill if I modify std::ifstream m_infile into std::ifstream m_infile[MAX_THREADS] and use OpenMP thread ID (passed as parameter).
3. (similar to 2.) Create N temporary instances of Loaders (where N = number of threads). In my case, that means that my LoaderManager has to clones its loaders.
4. To pass m_infile as a parameter of loadFromFile (or a private member of resource).
5. Use the idea of 1. with the fact that my resources are heterogeneous:

instead of:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i = 0; i < X; ++i)
{
    LoaderR1.loadFromFile(filenameR1[i], &resourcesR1[i]);
}
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i = 0; i < Y; ++i)
{
    LoaderR2.loadFromFile(filenameR2[i], &resourcesR2[i]);
}
...
```

To do that:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i = 0; i < min(X, Y); ++i)
{
    LoaderR1.loadFromFile(filenameR1[i], &resourcesR1[i]);
    LoaderR2.loadFromFile(filenameR2[i], &resourcesR2[i]);
}
```

Where X != Y and where:

```
Resource1 resourcesR1[X]; string filenamesR1[X] = { "fileR1_1.txt", "fileR1_2.txt", ... "fileR1_X.txt" };
Resource2 resourcesR2[Y]; string filenamesR2[Y] = { "fileR2_1.txt", "fileR2_2.txt", ... "fileR2_Y.txt" };
...

ResourceN resourcesRn[Z]; string filenamesRn[Z] = { "fileRn_1.txt", "fileRn_2.txt", ... "fileRn_Z.txt" };
```

That means: each threads loads N Resource1 and N Resource2. while mutex protects R1 against R1 (and R2 against R2) it allows to load R1 and R2 together.

So how to modify my class to reach my goal ? Note: I want to load resources at init time but not "on the fly", during the runtime, like explained in [OpenGL loading resource in separated thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331174/opengl-loading-resource-in-separated-thread) (while interesting but it's not what I'm looking at).

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason that m_infile needs to be a member variable. Just change your loader code to look like this:

```
virtual void loadFromFile(std::string const& filename, Resource1 &resource) override
{
    std::ifstream infile.open(filename, ...);
    ...
    resource.xxx = infile.read(...);
}
```

You haven't explained clearly why you thought the ifstream object needs to be a member variable, but its very unlikely that it really needs to be.

Comment: ! Thanks to point this ! You are right I did not explained well why I used m_infile. It's because I simplified a lot the code in my question. My real code calls lot of private methods and I use this member variable to avoid passing it as param. Your method works but I think it's sad to carry the context to each methods. In addition my "context" is a little more complex that just m_infile (I store temporary current states of the state machine).